# What's wrong with using object as a PropType?

Tags: javascript, reactjs

I see that [Airbnb's style guide](https://github.com/airbnb/javascript/tree/master/react) includes [`forbid-prop-types`](https://github.com/yannickcr/eslint-plugin-react/blob/master/docs/rules/forbid-prop-types.md) for type `object`. (as can be seen [here](https://github.com/airbnb/javascript/blob/b7aabb938d20f61ba3d617f473dc9006e6e48a59/packages/eslint-config-airbnb/rules/react.js#L41-L43))

Can someone explain why I would want to forbid the use of `PropType.object`?

Is it just that it's too vague?  And if so, how can I be more specific?

Comment: Did you follow the link? https://github.com/yannickcr/eslint-plugin-react/blob/master/docs/rules/forbid-prop-types.md

Comment: @elclanrs: um...yup.  i didn't see any explanation as to why i might want to use this rule.  nor did i see anything related to what proptypes i might use instead...did i miss something?

Comment: I suppose the description is a bit lacking in examples, but this is the reasoning as I understand -- "any should be replaced with, well, anything. array and object can be replaced with arrayOf and shape, respectively.". Think of a type like `a: any` or `a: Object` it is just not narrow enough, it can match anything.

Comment: That helps! Thanks @elclanrs!

Answer (score 5, accepted):

> Is it just that it's too vague?

Yes

> And if so, how can I be more specific?

Basically, they're saying if you use `object` you should *really* be using `shape` so you can specify what the key/values of the object are.

```
 // An object taking on a particular shape
  myObject: React.PropTypes.shape({
    color: React.PropTypes.string,
    fontSize: React.PropTypes.number
  }),
```

Comment: Ah! Excellent! That's what I was looking for!  Thanks @Jack!

Comment: @sfletche No problem. Happy to help!